# I can't retrieve cookies using cherrypy: what is the problem?

Tags: python, http, cookies, session-cookies, cherrypy

I'm working on a web page and i want to save cookie. I can set them  [as shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H0GH.png). But when i try to request them i only get session id. Here is the print when i set them:

```
Set-Cookie: confirm=True 
Set-Cookie: role=resercher
Set-Cookie: session_id=49c5ae1aee547fe542d6a93c276331f038a89591; expires=Fri, 16 Oct 2020 10:53:08 GMT; Max-Age=3600; Path=/
Set-Cookie: token=T7QrDqRLV0
Set-Cookie: uname=sato96
```

Here is the way i set them:

```
            cookie = cherrypy.response.cookie
            cookie["uname"] = dati["uname"]
            cookie["token"] = token
            u="reposleep"+dati["uname"]
            cookie["confirm"] = self.uh.reference[u]["confirm"]
            cookie["role"] = self.uh.reference[u]["role"]
            print(cookie)
            if token!="":
                cherrypy.response.cookie["uname"]['max-age']=3600*24*7
                cherrypy.response.cookie["token"]['max-age']=3600*24*7
                cherrypy.response.cookie["confirm"]['max-age']=3600*24*7
                cherrypy.response.cookie["role"]['max-age']=3600*24*
```

Then here is the parte where i try to retrieve them:

```
                cookies = cherrypy.request.cookie
                print(cookies["session_id"])
                
                try:
                    token = cookies["token"].value
                    uname = cookies["uname"].value
                    print(token)
                    print(uname)
                    ans=self.remember(token,uname)
                    print(ans)
                    if ans == True:
                        #setto di nuovo i tempi dei cookie
                        cherrypy.response.cookie["uname"]['max-age']=3600*24*7
                        cherrypy.response.cookie["token"]['max-age']=3600*24*7
                        cherrypy.response.cookie["role"]['max-age']=3600*24*7
                        cherrypy.response.cookie["confirm"]['max-age']=3600*24*7
                        s="Download.html"
                    else:
                        s="Login.html"
                except:
                    s="Login.html"
```

If i tried to delete try statement i get a key error: in fact, when i print "cookie" variable i get a dict with a single key: session_id.
Someone can help me? I don't know how to solve this problem. I haven't idea about what kind of problem i could have.

Comment: Well you don't set them, you assign the dictionary `cherrypy.response.cookie` to `cookie` but you never change the `cherrypy.response.cookie` dictionary itself, you only change the `cookie` dictionary, try to insert a `cherry.response.cookie = cookie` before that `if token!="":` statement

Comment: I tried but even in this case it doesn't work properly. I noticed, instead, that it set automatically the path "/localhost:8080", while the single cookie i can get is session_id that has path "/". If i force to set cookies' paths to "/" it works great. I don't why, also thinking to the fact that it works even if i did that error that you noticed in your answer